# query with top and order by - convert from MsSql to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert this query from MsSql syntax to Oracle syntax:

```
select top 1 (convert(varchar, UPDATED_DATE, 23)) as date from DA_CATEGORY order by date desc
```

How do I do this?
I need the data from both DB types to be the same string / value.

Comment: Put `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` after the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fetch` clause as follows:

```
select to_char(UPDATED_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') as date 
from DA_CATEGORY 
order by UPDATED_DATE desc
fetch first row only
```